# How to remove active class from default tab to another tab based on the URL?

Tags: jquery

I want a John's tab to be active using the class "active" when the page loads. However, if the URL ends with a specific hashtag (in this case #cindy), I want Cindy's tab to activate when the page loads instead (example: 'www.index.html#cindy').

I've gotten the page to activate John's tab so far, but I don't know where to go from here to make go to Cindy's tab based off the URL.

Any help would be appreciated.

**CSS**

```
#main-container .onPage.active {
    display: block;
}
#main-container .onPage {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="btnList" id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="tab linkSection" href="#james"><span>James</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="tab linkSection" href="#cindy"><span>Cindy</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="onPage" id="james">
            <div>
                <h1 class="icon"><span class="b"></span>Meet James</h1><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="onPage" id="cindy">
            <div>
                <h1 class="icon"><span class="b"></span>Meet Cindy</h1><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#james.onPage").addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get hash from url and check if it is blank or not and take decision from that which one to activate.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash) {
        $("div" + hash + ".onPage").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $("div#james.onPage").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a great foundation, I solved it with this: `$(document).ready(function() {
 var hash = window.location.hash;
 if (hash === "#cindy") {
  $("div" + "#cindy" + ".onPage").addClass("active");
 } else if (hash === "#james") {
  $("div" + "#james" + ".onPage").addClass("active");
 } else {
  $("div#james.onPage").addClass("active");
 }
});
`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.hash` to get hash from url.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if($("div" + hash + ".onPage").length > 0) {
        $("div" + hash + ".onPage").first().addClass("active");
    } else {
        $("div#james.onPage").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that makes both tabs active by default.

Comment: I updated my answer. If hash not exist, so `first()` active first tab, else active hash element. @Addy